# "Pointer to member" in python

Tags: python, member

Newbie question about python syntaxis. I have some function calls like following

```
summaryA = do_something(lambda info: (info.a, 1)). \
    .do_other() \
    .do_anoter() \
    .saveAsTextFile('/output/path/a.tsv')

summaryJ = do_something(lambda info: (info.j, 1)). \
    .do_other() \
    .do_anoter() \
    .saveAsTextFile('/output/path/j.tsv')

summaryZ = do_something(lambda info: (info.z, 1)). \
    .do_other() \
    .do_anoter() \
    .saveAsTextFile('/output/path/z.tsv')
```

`info` is an instance of class `Info`.

These calls are pretty alike. So, I would like to remove copy-paste and get something like following (This is just idea, I am not "native pythonian")

```
summaryA = super_do(Info.a, '/output/path/a.tsv')
summaryJ = super_do(Info.j, '/output/path/j.tsv')
summaryZ = super_do(Info.z, '/output/path/z.tsv')
```

How to write function `super_do`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def super_do(attr, path):
    return do_something(lambda info, attr=attr: (getattr(info, attr), 1)).\
        .do_other() \
        .do_another() \
        .saveAsTextFile(path)
```

You can then use it like this:

```
summaryA = super_do("a", "/output/path/a.tsv")
```